# What does the $ mean in erlang

Tags: erlang

what's the $ sign mean?

For example:

```
is_digit(Ch) ->
    $0 =< Ch andalso Ch =< $9.
```

I've also seen it been typed like:

```
$(, $), $+, $*
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` use to indicate character in ASCII. For example

```
1> $a.
97
2> $1.
49
3> [49,50].
"12"
4> $\n. ### newline character
10
```

Your function is meaning that the character input is digit or not.